# Access remote usb file from local pc and scripting capabilities

Tags: windows-10, usb, remote, psexec, copy

i have a few batch files running on a pc on the network, and i want them to be able to view and interact with a usb drive on a different Windows 10 (64bit) computer on the same network.

Is there a way by mapping the drive and assigning a permanent letter to it?
Is my only solution moving all the scripts and using psexec? What alternatives do i have?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add to your question: OS 32 or 64-bit? Add OS tag.

Comment: os is windows 10, 64 bit.